# Showing $\lvert\mathscr{B}_X\rvert=2^{n^2}$.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, binary, semigroups, finite-semigroups

This is Exercise 2.9.11 of Howie's *"Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory"*.

> Let $\mathscr{B}_X$ be the set of all binary relations on a set $X$, where $\lvert X\rvert=n$. Show that $\lvert\mathscr{B}_X\rvert=2^{n^2}$.

### My Attempt:

For each $(x, y)\in X\times X$, $(x, y)$ is either in a given binary relation on $X$ or it is not. Thus
$$\begin{align}
\lvert\mathscr{B}_X\rvert&=\lvert\{\text{is in, is not in}\}\rvert^{\lvert X\times X\rvert} \\
&=2^{\lvert X\times X\rvert} \\
&=2^{\lvert X\rvert^2} \\
&=2^{n^2}.
\end{align}$$ $\square$

### Thoughts:

Whilst, I suppose, my proof is satisfactory, I think it lacks rigour. Would you accept my proof?

Comment: Your proof is OK, doesn't lack rigour (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. A binary relation on $X$ can be represented by a Boolean $n \times n$ matrix. What is the number of Boolean $n \times n$matrices?